# How do I rotate a SCNNode to look at another node, whilst keeping its roll and pitch level with the camera?

Tags: scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I am using ARKit to direct people to a position in the physical world using an arrow attached to the camera node. Applying a lookAtConstraint to the arrow with a target of a node in the location I want almost does what I need. However, I need to stop the arrow from rolling left and right and pitching up and down. [Example of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzPVy.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting `isGimbalLockEnabled` to `true` to constrain the roll rotation? In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint/1468675-isgimballockenabled) Apple mentions: "For example, when constraining a camera to follow a moving object, setting this property to true ensures that the horizon remains level from the camera’s point of view."

If that still isn't what you're looking for, you may need to write a custom constraint using the class function `SCNTransformConstraint.orientationConstraint`. You could write the constraint as a secondary constraint that basically restricts rotations on the X and Z axes, or you could write your own look-at constraint with more restrictions (in which case I'd recommend looking at the `simd.look(at:)` [function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881870-simdlook) and then restricting the orientation axes from there).

This should get you most of the way there, or I can add some code in later if it doesn't seem to be working. Good luck!

Comment: isGimbalLockEnabled works to a dgree but I still get rotation I don't want. The best solution is to write a new constraint, but for now I will change the design.